# Is there a way to call a method in the gRPC service running on a remote machine using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, grpc, .net-6.0

I am new to C# and .NET. I am trying out a simple gRPC service using .NET 6. I was able to create a sample service with the predefined template in the VS2022. Now, instead of creating a .NET client to communicate with that gRPC service, I want to use PowerShell to communicate with that service, running on a remote machine. But I'm unsure how to do that.

So far I have tried using the below command and it didn't work,

```
$grpcservice = new-webserviceproxy -uri "http://localhost:5222/SamplegRPCService"
$grpcservice.Display("Hello There!")
```

BTW, this sample service will get a string as input and will display that string. (Currently testing it out by running the service from my local machine)

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful!

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Is your SampleRPCService a proper webservice? Did you get an error-message when creating the webserviceproxy?

Comment: @pelin72 Yes, I got a couple of errors when I run the cmd,
1) new-webserviceproxy : The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
2)You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

My understanding of these errors is that the -uri parameter I'm passing is not a valid one, But I was able to verify that the service was listening at a particular port.

Comment: RPC and SOAP web services are two different technologies. I can say that ```new-webserviceproxy``` cannot connect to a pure RPC-server. It is possible ONLY if your SamplegRPCService is multiprotocol. ```new-webserviceproxy``` requires a WSDL-file which is connected to the URI parameter. I would suggest connecting to the RPC-server via the CLI,: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md

Comment: There is no built-in support for gRPC in powershell. The snippet you provided tries to use a completely different protocol than gRPC and has no chance of working. What you can do from powershell is to invoke one of the existing command line tools that can communicate with gRPC server (e.g. https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) and invoke RPCs by specifying arguments on the commandline.